# SegFault calling main

Tags: c, loops, segmentation-fault, infinite

I've simplified this tiny bit of code that I would expect to be an infinite loop down to:

```
#include <stddef.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    main(argc, NULL);
  }
}
```

(Whether or not you pass argv on doesn't really matter. The compiler tends to optimise it out, anyways.)

However, under both clang 9.0.1 and gcc 9.2.0, the above code segfaults with an address boundary error.

Looking at the asm (that I dumped [here](https://gist.github.com/shakna-israel/81d32d39547fde95249b74522998bd17)), I'm still not seeing anything that would cause this to go haywire.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour (no diagnostic required) so anything can happen

Comment: What's your execution command?

Comment: You're recursing infinitely.  This will exhaust your stack very quickly.  You're guaranteed to get an error like this.

Comment: Calling `main` in C++ is illegal, however I don't believe that text appears in the C standard. Which is why flags such as `pedantic` error for a C++ compiler, but not the C compiler.

Comment: The stack size, as expected is a single frame. There's no allocation happening. No limit being hit.

Comment: That's infinite recursion, not tail recursion, and every recursive call pushes a new stack frame. You can see that at the `main` entry point. So eventually the stack will overflow. (It doesn't matter that the arguments are the same. It still needs a stack frame to hold the return pointer.) If you compile with optimisation, of course, the results are radically different.

Comment: As already stated, there's only a single stack frame, regardless of optimisation level.

Comment: @s4b3r6: Just because you stated that doesn't make it true. As I said, you can see the stack frame being created at the beginning of `main`, after which the program recursively calls `main`, which will create another stack frame, and so on until it runs out of stack. And at -O1 and above, you instead get `main: xor eax, eax; ret`, because the compiler notices that the program has no observable effects.

Comment: @rici Just because you stated that doesn't make it true. As I said, that isn't what I'm seeing.

Comment: Suggest keeping an eye on the stack pointer SP or the block pointer BP  In either case, you will see the pointer moving with each iteration of the call main loop

Comment: @TomKarzes there's no guarantee as the compiler may detect the situation and take arbitrary action (e.g. recursion optimization,  remove the code, abort program)

Comment: @M.M That's true, it could eliminate the recursive call and turn it into an infinite look (or reject it entirely).  So I suppose it could loop indefinitely without blowing out its stack in that case.

Comment: @s4b3r6 in the gist you yourself pointed to, there is a recursive call to main (which I believe is at line 107). You keep saying there is a single stack frame. Do you have any evidence for this? Do you know that every time a function is called a new stack frame is created. Even though it doesn't make any allocation, it occupies some space? Also as many have pointed already, non-terminating programs are undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using gdb, it's pretty easy to miss the fact that a new stack frame is being used on each call. By default, gdb shows you only one stack frame for `main`, no matter how many recursions are performed:

```
$ cat recursive_main.c
#include <stddef.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    main(argc, NULL);
  }
}
$ clang-9 -o recursive_main -Wall -g recursive_main.c
$ ./recursive_main
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ gdb -q ./recursive_main 
Reading symbols from ./recursive_main...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004b6: file recursive_main.c, line 4.
(gdb) commands
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>bt
>end
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/rici/src/tmp/recursive_main 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8) at recursive_main.c:4
4         for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
#0  main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8) at recursive_main.c:4
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
4         for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
#0  main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
(gdb) 
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
4         for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
#0  main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
(gdb) 
Continuing.
```

But if we print out the stack pointer at each entry, we can see that it's decremented each time:

```
$ gdb -q ./recursive_main 
Reading symbols from ./recursive_main...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004b6: file recursive_main.c, line 4.
(gdb) commands
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>info r esp
>end
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/rici/src/tmp/recursive_main 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8) at recursive_main.c:4
4         for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
esp            0xffffddc0       -8768
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
4         for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
esp            0xffffdd90       -8816
(gdb) 
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
4         for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
esp            0xffffdd60       -8864
(gdb) 
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
4         for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
esp            0xffffdd30       -8912
(gdb)
```

So the stack is extended by 0x30 (48) bytes by each recursive call.

The reason for this curious behaviour is that gdb deliberately ends the backtrace when it hits `main`. It does that because the real entry point of an executable is not `main`, but rather some platform-dependent code which sets everything up so that `main` can be called, and then calls `main`. As a consequence, gdb doesn't really know where the stack "begins". Or rather, it knows where the executable's stack begins, but it has no idea where the program's stack begins. It would be a bit confusing to include functions in the executable's setup code in every backtrace, so by default gdb just stops walking the stack when it hits a frame whose entry point is `main`. If you know about this option, you can control it:

```
(gdb) help set backtrace past-main
Set whether backtraces should continue past "main".
Normally the caller of "main" is not of interest, so GDB will terminate
the backtrace at "main".  Set this variable if you need to see the rest
of the stack trace.
```

And with the option set, you can see the various stack frames corresponding to the recursive calls to `main`:

```
$ gdb -q ./recursive_main
Reading symbols from ./recursive_main...done.
(gdb) set backtrace past-main 1
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004b6: file recursive_main.c, line 4.
(gdb) commands
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>bt
>end
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/rici/src/tmp/recursive_main 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8) at recursive_main.c:4
4         for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
#0  main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8) at recursive_main.c:4
#1  0x00007ffff7a05b97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x4004a0 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8, init=<optimized out>, 
    fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdeb8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
#2  0x00000000004003da in _start ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
4         for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
#0  main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
#1  0x00000000004004d5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8) at recursive_main.c:5
#2  0x00007ffff7a05b97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x4004a0 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8, init=<optimized out>, 
    fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdeb8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
#3  0x00000000004003da in _start ()
(gdb) 
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
4         for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
#0  main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
#1  0x00000000004004d5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:5
#2  0x00000000004004d5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8) at recursive_main.c:5
#3  0x00007ffff7a05b97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x4004a0 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8, init=<optimized out>, 
    fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdeb8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
#4  0x00000000004003da in _start ()
(gdb) 
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
4         for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
#0  main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:4
#1  0x00000000004004d5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:5
#2  0x00000000004004d5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x0) at recursive_main.c:5
#3  0x00000000004004d5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8) at recursive_main.c:5
#4  0x00007ffff7a05b97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x4004a0 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8, init=<optimized out>, 
    fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdeb8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
#5  0x00000000004003da in _start ()
(gdb)
```

But while it's probably good to know about this gdb option (and I didn't know about it until 15 minutes ago), it's not really necessary. You can see the code which creates the stack frame at offset 1120 in the disassembly that you linked, although it's easier to see in the `-S` output (or by using the handy service at [http://gcc.godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/HDvkS3)):

```
0000000000001120 :
    1120:   55                      push   %rbp
    1121:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1124:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
    1128:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    112f:   89 7d f8                mov    %edi,-0x8(%rbp)
    1132:   48 89 75 f0             mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
    1136:   c7 45 ec 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x14(%rbp)
    113d:   8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
    1140:   3b 45 f8                cmp    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
    1143:   0f 8d 1a 00 00 00       jge    1163 
    1149:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    114b:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
    114d:   8b 7d f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%edi
    1150:   e8 cb ff ff ff          callq  1120
```

As you can see, on entry to `main` (which is at the offset shown, 1120), first `%rbp` is [push](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push)ed onto the stack, resulting in %esp being decremented by 8 (for 64-bit mode). Then the stack pointer is decremented by an additional 0x20 (32), leaving space to save the registers that will be used (which include the registers used to pass arguments to the called function, and the register used to store the value of `i`). Finally (after a bit of work), the `callq` instruction at offset 1150 is executed, which pushes the address of the next instruction onto the stack, using up another 8 bytes.

So a 48-byte stack frame is pushed on each recursive call. And since the recursion never terminates, that must eventually hit the protected page which precedes the stack, at which point a segfault is signalled.

Note that this does not happen with clang at any positive optimisation level:

```
$ clang-9 -o recursive_main -Wall -g -O1 recursive_main.c
$ ./recursive_main
$ gdb -q ./recursive_main 
Reading symbols from ./recursive_main...done.
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004004a0 <+0>:     xor    %eax,%eax
   0x00000000004004a2 <+2>:     retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Here, the compiler has taken advantage of the standard's requirement (in §6.8.5/6, see below) that a loop which has no observable effect can be assumed to terminate; in this case, the compiler assumes that it terminates immediately, which is legitimate because nothing will change before the loop eventually terminates.

GCC does not seem to perform that optimisation, by the way, so it will segfault regardless of optimisation level. At least, that's what happened in my test.

---

#### Standard C, §6.8.5 :

> 6. An iteration statement whose controlling expression is not a constant expression, that performs no input/output operations, does not access volatile objects, and performs no synchronization or atomic operations in its body, controlling expression, or (in the case of a **for** statement) its *expression-3*, may be assumed by the implementation to terminate.

Comment: That's interesting that gdb doesn't show the stack frame.  It works correctly with other recursive functions.  Is this a gdb or gcc bug?

Comment: @NateEldredge It's some sort of special case for `main`. Copying `main` to `mymain`, changing so `mymain` calls itself and `main` calls `mymain` once, causes `gdb` to see multiple frames: `#include <stddef.h>  int mymain(int argc, char *argv[]) { for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) { mymain(argc, NULL); } }  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { mymain(argc, NULL); }`

Comment: @Craig (and Nate): OK, I found the explanation. Added to the answer. (http://i.imgur.com/pmRJX.jpg)

Comment: Aha.  Nice find!

Answer (score 0):

The program causes undefined behaviour due to no forward progress. C11 6.8.5/6:

> An iteration statement whose controlling expression is not a constant expression, that performs no input/output operations, does not access volatile objects, and performs no
>   synchronization or atomic operations in its body, controlling expression, or (in the case of a for statement) its expression-3, may be assumed by the implementation to
>   terminate.

So the compiler can assume the `for` loop terminates. Since execution of the loop would actually never terminate, the behaviour is undefined by omission and therefore anything can happen.